# Can't Find Device with PyUSB

Tags: python, pyusb

I found my device's VID and PID in the properties for the device on windows, which are `256` for the VID and `006` for the PID. I can't seem to get pyusb to find it. From what I've seen, most people put the VID and PID in hex, which I tried and it still doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

VID = 256
PID = 6

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=VID, idProduct=PID)
```

`dev` is always `None`. Any clue what I did wrong?

EDIT:

I just tested with another device with a VID of `0x046D` and a PID of `0xC21D` and it still returns `None`.

EDIT 2:

I have libusb installed and I've tried running the script in both Python 3.4 and Python 2.7. It always returns `None`.

Comment: Is the ID `256` or `0x256` (hex)?

Comment: @KlausD. Windows says the ID is `256` which is 100 in hex.

Comment: What does `usb.core.find(find_all=True)` return? Or try other arguments for `find()` as well!

Comment: @KlausD. `<generator object device_iter at 0x00000000063FE048>`

Comment: So, it found something. Iterate the generator!

Comment: @KlausD. I iterated through it and it seems to be empty. I did `for i in dev:` and it never looped.

Comment: `VID=0x01 and PID =0x00` ? Remove all drivers for your USB device. You are an Administrator ?

Comment: @dsgdfg I am an Administrator and I still get `None` from `VID=0x01, PID=0x00`.

Comment: @dsgdfg So apparently I needed to use libusb and install the driver for the device. I thought I needed the `libusb1` library. xD

Comment: This was my issues as well. usb.core.find(find_all=True) returned nothing on my Windows 10 machine until I used the inf-wizard to generate and install the driver.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up needing `inf-wizard.exe` from libusb to install drivers to my USB devices so it could work with PyUSB. I did not need to install `libusb1` for Python.